# How to implement AFTER INSERT Trigger in Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, sql-insert

I am trying to implement after insert trigger in PLSQL. 
The goal is to check if there are  multiple (>1) rows having specific status for each client. 
If so I'd like to rise an exception and roll the insertion back.
I am struggling with implementing warning-free query, which causes error during insertion.
 How could I manage this?
Here is my implemented trigger which I guess needs some changes.

```
CREATE TRIGGER blatrigger
    AFTER INSERT
    ON BLATABLE
    REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    exception_name EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (exception_name, -20999);
BEGIN
    if (select count(*) as counter from BLATABLE where CLIENTID = :NEW.CLIENTID and STATUS='PENDING').counter > 1
    THEN
        raise exception_name;
    END IF;
END;
```

Here is the table itself:

```
create table BLATABLE
(
    ID            NUMBER(19) not null primary key,
    CLIENTID      NUMBER(10),
    CREATED       TIMESTAMP(6),
    STATUS        VARCHAR2(255 char)
);
```

Comment: What is the aim of the locally declared exception? The caller will just get an anonymous ORA-20999 error with no information. It would be better to `raise_application_error(-20999, 'Some message describing the problem including diagnostic details');`

Comment: By the way, `REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD` doesn't do anything. I'd leave it out altogether unless you want to reference things using some non-default label name.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson yes, your comment really makes sense. I just tried to make the trigger work at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Statement Level Trigger, rather than a Row Level by removing `FOR EACH ROW`, and converting to your code as below :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER blatrigger
  AFTER INSERT ON BLATABLE
  REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD

DECLARE
  counter        INT;
  exception_name EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(exception_name, -20999);
BEGIN
  SELECT MAX(COUNT(*))
    INTO counter
    FROM BLATABLE
   WHERE STATUS = 'PENDING'
   GROUP BY CLIENTID;
     
  IF counter > 1 THEN
    RAISE exception_name;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

where

- the SELECT statement need to be removed from `IF .. THEN` conditional
- Most probably, the mutating table error would raise for Row Level Trigger case

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f7ed4cf94ef9e639a64eb962c241d7ef)</kbd>

Comment: Good.  However, at the moment the select could raise TOO_MANY_ROWS due to the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: yeah you're right @TonyAndrews , thanks, I needed to wrap with MAX() there ...

Comment: The creation of the TRIGGER went well but whenever I try to insert data into the table warnings occur:
[4091] ORA-04091: table BLATABLE is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
[2020-09-04 14:01:16] ORA-06512: at "blatrigger", line 6
[2020-09-04 14:01:16] ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'blatrigger'
[2020-09-04 14:01:16] Position: 17

Comment: are you sure that you created as stated within the answer @MikheilZhghenti Consider [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=69fed4ced749babca0a065ed6f458c49)

Comment: You are right. I just missed removing  FOR EACH ROW.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan just a little note in your provided demo: there you insert ID,Status pairs. As the problem requires we need to restrict ClientID,Status only the case where Status is 'PENDING' and it's duplicated (>1) per clientId.

Comment: Of course @MikheilZhghenti , Try to add `BEGIN INSERT INTO BLATABLE(ID,STATUS) VALUES(5,'ACTIVE'); END; /` to the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=533c0e60f8b45db82f3a1c1cf563e11f) which will be successful

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan In my understanding, there should be written as following:
INSERT INTO BLATABLE(ID, CLIENTID, STATUS).

So, CLIENTID is needed as well - as we have a restriction on it. Right ?

Comment: Yes, I missed clientid @MikheilZhghenti you're right , now replaced, have a look at the new demo within the answer.

Answer (score 4):

> The goal is to check if there are multiple (>1) rows having specific status for each client. If so I'd like to rise an exception and roll the insertion back.

No need for a trigger. It looks like a simple unique constraint should get the job done here:

```
create table blatable (
    id            number(19) not null primary key,
    clientid      number(10),
    created       timestamp(6),
    status        varchar2(255 char),
    constraint blaconstraint unique (clientid, status)
);
```

The unique constraint prevents duplicates on `(clientid, status)` across the whole table. If a DML operation (insert, update) attempts to generate a duplicate, an error is raised and the operation is rolled back.

If, on the other end, you want to allow only one "PENDING" status per user, then you can use a unique index as follows:

```
create unique index bla_index
    on blatable( (case when status = 'PENDING' then clientid end) );
```

Comment: Actually, no. Because a status could be different - not only 'PENDING'. But I need to restrict only 'PENDING' one.